# I can't create Android or iPhone project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, iphone, xamarin

I'm in xamarin and I'm trying to create android projects in visual studio but there is a problem when i try to create a new android project there is no template and i have been installed Xamarin successfully please help me 
thank you
[the available templates under c#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn52z.png)

Comment: Didn't you ask the question today already?

Comment: @l.Guthardt if you know the solution please share with me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checked all checkboxes under Mobile development with .Net when installing xamarin from visual studio installer

see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows) and new project window will look like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?tabs=vswin) after successfully installed.

Comment: Then deinstall VS 2017 and completely reinstall everything.

Comment: OK that is the only solution that i have  thank you my friend

Comment: @ZADICKEDEÑ 'everything is correct but still there is a problem' What problem? Be specific. We can't see your screen ;)

Comment: @nilsK check the image to see my screen , but already i solve the problem and the solution is reinstalling the visual studio. thank you all of you